# How to remove Material Angular CSS codes from head tag?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

I'm learning AngularJS & Material Angular Design. But Material Design is including CSS codes between `<head>` tags. I attached a screenshot.

How will I remove these codes from head tags and include in a css file?

[image: Angular Material Design]

Answer (score 2):

These tags are generated by angular-material library at runtime. So you cannot put these in css files.
Also, there is no point of doing this. It is handled by `angulat-material` library automatically for you.